# Problems with meego image on windows

Tags: n900, meego

I've got windows and want to install meego... but the image is raw and the win32diskimages only supports .IMG.

What is wrong, is there a writer that supports .raw (the format of the image unpacked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to download a MeeGo Live image and put that on a USB stick. Boot from the USB stick and you will have a running MeeGo install that will not affect your Windows software.

More info here: http://meego.com/devices/netbook/installing-meego-your-netbook